# getJSON() to access data at multiple levels

Tags: ajax, json, getjson

I'm trying to use `.getJSON` to extract the data from this validating .json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Claim": {
                "id": "3567",
                "user_id": "341",
                "expiration": "2013-07-06 23:59:59",
                "content": "Apples",
                "point": "85.71",
                "exp": "Jul 6, 2013"
            },
            "User": {
                 "score": "-1030.17",
                "id": "341"
            },
            "ClaimResponse": {
                "point": "80",
                "response_type": "yeah",
                "claim_id": "3567"
            },
            "viewer": {
                "isOwner": "0",
                "isResponsed": "1",
                "response": "yeah",
                "lockedInPoint": "80"
            }
        },
        {
            "Claim": {
                "id": "3576",
                "user_id": "342",
                "expiration": "2013-06-15 00:00:00",
                "content": "Oranges",
                "point": "86.42",
                "exp": "Jun 15, 2013"
            },
            "User": {
                "score": "-3128.13",
                "id": "342"
            },
            "ClaimResponse": {
                "point": "71",
                "response_type": "yeah",
                "claim_id": "3576"
            },
            "viewer": {
                "isOwner": "0",
                "isResponsed": "1",
                "response": "yeah",
                "lockedInPoint": "71"
            }
        },
        {
            "Claim": {
                "id": "3577",
                "user_id": "342",
                "expiration": "2013-07-01 00:00:00",
                "content": "Peanuts",
                "point": "80.25",
                "exp": "Jul 1, 2013"
            },
            "User": {
                "score": "-3128.13",
                "id": "342"
            },
            "ClaimResponse": {
                "point": "67",
                "response_type": "yeah",
                "claim_id": "3577"
            },
            "viewer": {
                "isOwner": "0",
                "isResponsed": "1",
                "response": "yeah",
                "lockedInPoint": "67"
            }
        }
    ],
    "errors": [],
    "success": true,
    "code": 200
}
```

(A snippet of many records)  I've never tried to extract data multiple levels down like this, and I can't get at it.

My code's pretty straightforward:

```
$.getJSON("/api/getUserClaims.json",function(data){

          $.each(data.Claim, function(i,Claim){
            content = '<p>' + Claim.id + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo("#my-claims");
            alert(content);
          });
      });
```

According to my console, the json is loading properly.  I've tried getting at it a few ways, using `data.Claim[0].id` to grab it as an array instead of object.  Hopefully I'm overlooking something simple.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `data.Claim`.

You have an array in there first, so it would be `data[0].Claim`, `data[1].Claim` etc.

```
$.each(data, function(i,x){
        var Claim = x.Claim;
        content = '<p>' + Claim.id + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#my-claims");
        alert(content);
      });
```

Comment: thanks.  This makes sense.  However, This is still returning 'Claim is undefined' errors.

Comment: Got it!  I had to modify the function to `$.getJSON("/api/getUserClaims.json",function(json){` ... and the first line and the rest was perfect: `$.each(json.data, function(i,x){`.  If you understand why it works with `json` and not `data`, I'd love to know...

Answer (score 0):

The first claim ID is

```
data[0]["Claim"]["id"]
```

Data is an array of objects. To visualize this better, use Chrome or Firefox developer tool. You can browse your data and suddenly it becomes much clearer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  This clarified everything perfectly.